How can I get the XML TAG Replaced
I've tried a few things but I can't get it to replace the products tag


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://api.itscope.com/2.1/info/schema/developer.xsd">
    <product>
        <name>Example Product</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
    </product>
</products>



and here is my XSLT


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

    <!-- Identitätstransformation: Kopiert alle Nodes und Attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Spezielle Transformation für das <products>-Tag mit den speziellen Namespaces und Attributen -->
    <xsl:template match="products[@xsi:schemaLocation]">
        <products>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>



I think it is about namespaces but i can't find the problem.
this is my Goal:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Example Product</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
    </product>
</products>




Do you want to remove the xsi:schemaLocation attribute from the products element? Then simply use <xsl:template match="products/xsi:schemaLocation"/> plus the identity transformation template.

Yes that is what i want! Can you post the complete XSLT here?

If you use the identity transformation as the base template and want to remove certain nodes add an empty template matching those nodes e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- drop attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="products/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>


<xsl:template match="products/@xsi:schemaLocation]"/> should be <xsl:template match="products/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>

@SiebeJongebloed, right, I correct it, thanks.
